# strip base64 img string from a html

Tags: xml, bash

I have a html file, an base64 image is encoded in this file.

```
</div><img src='data:image/png;base64,{base64-string} class='pic' style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;index:7102;'/></div></div>
```

I would like to use bash shell to extract the base64 img string and save to a png file.

My major question is how to strip the base64 string from the html.  (`{base64-string}`)

I tried to use  xmllint  --xpath

but unnecessary string

```
class='pic' style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;index:7102;'/>
```

was included.

Comment: Questions must provide a [mcve]. Try to complete it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source HTML is problematic from a minimal, reproducible example standpoint.  Your tags do not open/close properly, and the single quotes on the `src=...` are not closed.  If the source HTML is altered to:

```
<div><img src='data:image/png;base64,{base64-string}' class='pic' style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;index:7102;'/></div>
```

You can extract the base64 string using `xmllint` and bash parameter expansion:

```
$ var=$(echo "<div><img src='data:image/png;base64,{base64-string}' class='pic' style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;index:7102;'/></div>" | xmllint --xpath "string(//div/img/@src)" -); echo "${var##*,}"
{base64-string}
```